# My @media queries don't seem to be overriding my original CSS

Tags: css, media, mobile

I've tried everything. I've tried to refresh the page multiple times, I've tried uploading various ways to ensure that the css file is updated. Nothing seems to work. My media queries don't seem to be overriding them, but in Dreamweaver, they work just fine.

Here is the code for the CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #636466;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#logo  {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(wordsbyperla_wordpress%20header_small.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 24px;
    max-width: 411px;
    background-size: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-position: bottom;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav   {
    top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 3%;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: auto;
    top: auto;
}
.menu-item   {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: "Courier";
    background-color: transparent;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.menu-item a  , .menu-item a:visited, .menu-item a:active{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
    color: #EC2726;
}
#searchform {
    font-family: "Courier";
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#s {
    border: none;
    font-family: "Courier";
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#searchsubmit {
    border: none;
    font-family: "Courier";
    margin: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

#contentWrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.meta {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Courier";
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 70%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.meta div {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.meta div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.meta div a:hover, .meta div a:active {
    color: #EC2726;
}

.meta span {
    color: #EC2726;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
#tags  {
    color: #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    right: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.meta .pagination  {
    position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Courier";
    bottom: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    right: 70%;
    width: 23%;
}
.meta .pagination ul {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.meta .pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Courier";
    color: #000;
}
.meta .pagination a   , .meta .pagination a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.meta .pagination a:hover , .meta .pagination a:active {
    color: #EC2726;
}
.meta2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 21%;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-width: 300px;
    top: -50px;
}
.meta2 a            , .meta2 a:visited  {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
a:hover,      a:active, .meta2 a:hover{
    color: #EC2726;
}
.entry p {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    /* [disabled]background-color: #f7f7f7; */
    border-top: 3px inset #636466;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 10px;
    /* [disabled]display: inline; */
    left: 0px;
}
footer ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3%;
    /* [disabled]margin-left: 5px; */
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    list-style: none;
}
```

And here is the code for the @media query for the iPhone 6:

```
/*iphone 6+*/
@media (device-width:414px) and (device-width:736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
    #contentWrap {
    top: 85px;
}
#logo {
    width: 90%;
}
.meta {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    top: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.meta div {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.meta2 {
    width: 96%;
    max-width: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
.entry p {
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.meta .pagination {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
footer ul {
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
}
footer li {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
nav {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    top: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    /* [disabled]margin-left: 3%; */
    /* [disabled]margin-right: 8%; */
    width: 100%;
}
.meta div {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Technically this does not appear to be a WordPress issue it's a CSS issue, you may get better results asking your question in a CSS specific forum.

Comment: You need to post a sample.